# Second order non-linear differential equation (damped oscillator)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this second-order non-linear differential equation. $m$, $k$, $t$ are all constants. This equation describes the position of a sprung, damped mass.

$$mf''(t) = -k(f(t)-1) -c(f'(t)$$

where

$$f(1)\approx1; f(0)\approx0; f'(0)=0; f''(0)=0$$

A simplified example:

$$f''(t) = -180(f(t)-1) -12(f'(t)$$

Has a verified (graphed) solution of:

$$f(t) = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-6t}(-2e^{6t}+sin(12t)+2cos(12t)) $$

The goal is to find an equation where we can supply the mass, spring and damping constants and then find the position over time.

I am concerned that will not be possible, perhaps the correct format for this equation is

$$mf''(t,m,k,c) = -k(f(t,m,k,c)-1) -c(f'(t,m,k,c)$$

It has been many years since I took differential equations and any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

With $$y=f(t)$$

Your equation is $$ my''+cy'+ky=k $$

The Characteristic polynomial is $$ m\lambda ^2+c\lambda +k=0$$

The eigenvalues are roots of the above equation.

The solution to the homogeneous equation are found to be the linear combinations of $e^{\lambda _1t}$ and $e^{\lambda _2t}$ and your particular solution is simply $y_p=1$ 
the general solution is $$y=f(t) =c_1 e^{\lambda _1t} + c_2 e^{\lambda _2t}+1$$ You then find the coefficients from the initial values.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thank you, where can I learn the steps to resolve the coefficients. I apologize for the spoon feeding, I haven't touched a DifEqs in years.

Comment: You need some information for example f(0)=0 and f'(0)=1 to plug in your general solution and solve for coefficients. For a second order equation you just need two initial values to find the two coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote :

> A simplified example:
>   $$f''(t) = -180(f(t)-1) -12(f'(t)$$
>   Has a verified solution of:
>   $$1-\frac{1}{2}e^{6t}(-2e^{6t}+sin(12t)+2cos(12t)) $$

This is false. Your solution doesn't agree with the ODE. Check it.

Obviously there is a typo in the first exponential which should be $e^{-6t}$ instead of $e^{6t}$.

But even the typo corrected your solution is not solution of the ODE. Check it.

The correct general solution of $\quad f''(t) = -180(f(t)-1) -12(f'(t)\quad$ is :
$$f(t)=1+c_1e^{-6t}\sin(12t)+c_2e^{-6t}\cos(12t)$$
The conditions $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=0$ imply $c_1=0$ and $c_2=0$. Thus the unique solution is 
$$f(t)=1$$
Thus $f(0)=1$. This is not $f(0)\approx 1$.

Please, provide a correct example and improve the wording of your question to make it understandable. What you exactly expect is rather fishy.

NOTE : It is strange that you specify $y'(0)=y''(0)=0$ because the solution becomes constant, that is $f$ doesn't depend on $t$ and remains equal to $f(0)$ any values of $m,k,c,t$.

Comment: Hello, I realized a typo in my solution. I say it is verified because it provides a realistic spring curve where $f(0)\approx0$ and $f(1)\approx1$. I am not sure where to discuss these types of questions so I came to stack exchange, any recommendations for making this question better are much appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to come up with an equation to describe damped spring motion for the purpose of animation. I have been able to use Wolfram Alpha to find a single solution where $m=1$, $k=180$ and $c=20$, but I would like to be able to set the mass, spring constant, and damping coefficient to generate animation curves instead of having to solve with Wolfram and type it in every time. I have noticed that $m=1$, $k=180$, $c\geq36$ the result turns from an oscillating function (using sin/cos) into a critically damped (using e^x only) function

Comment: Use the general solution already given by Mohammad Riazi-Kermani. $$f(t) =c_1 e^{\lambda _1t} + c_2 e^{\lambda _2t}+1$$ First compute $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ by solving the equation $$m\lambda ^2+c\lambda +k=0$$ Then compute $c_1$ and $c_2$ by solving the system $$\lambda_1c_1+\lambda_2c_2=y'(0)$$ $$\lambda_1^2c_1+\lambda_2^2c_2=y''(0)$$ Don't forget that if $y'(0)=0$ and $y''(0)=0$ the fonction $f(t)$ is necessarily constant.

Comment: If the solutions $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are not real, that is complex on the form $\lambda=\alpha+i \beta$ then $e^{(\alpha +i \beta)t}$ the solution becomes $$f(t)=e^{\alpha t}(C_1\sin(\beta t)+C_2\cos(\beta t))+1$$ This explains why some solutions are osculating, some not oscilating, depending on the values of $m,c,k$.